# auto.hd.type = "cv" in mlp() function in nnfor package

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting

In running mlp() function of the nnfor package, you can allow the model to choose the number of hidden nodes through cross validation.

```
fit2 <- mlp(fit, auto.hd.type = "cv")
fit2$MSEH
```

I would just like to ask, what does the MSE values means for each number of hidden nodes if you let the mlp function select the number of hidden nodes. How does the computation was performed in getting these values?

[image]

This differs completely from the MSE of the model

[image]